# Highcharts - line between two categories

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a chart that is of type **column range** and my requirement is to have a line connecting two categories.

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/damseldeebi/ebtygovh/5/)

```
$(function() {  $('#container').highcharts({
chart: {
  type: 'columnrange',
  inverted: true
},
title: {
  text: 'Test'
},
subtitle: {
  text: 'Sample'
},
xAxis: {
  categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar'],
  visible: false
},
yAxis: {
  visible: false
},
legend: {
  enabled: false
},
series: [{
  name: 'Series1',
  data: [
    [0, 3],
    [0, 3],
    [0, 3]
  ],
  pointPlacement: -0.20,
  pointWidth: 50
}, {
  name: 'Series2',
  data: [
    [3, 6],
    [3, 6],
    [3, 6]
  ],
  pointPlacement: 0,
  pointWidth: 1
}, {
  name: 'Series3',
  data: [
    [6, 9],
    [6, 9],
    [6, 9]
  ],
  pointPlacement: 0.20,
  pointWidth: 50
}]   });});
```

How do I draw a line from one category to another?
Is there any property available?

Comment: You can add new line series in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/ebtygovh/6/ You can also use renderer.path http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.path If my comment will meet your requirements I will post it as an answer

Comment: @GrzegorzBlachliński this is what I was looking for. It is a great start for me.. thanks! pls post it an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to achieve similar chart by simply adding new line series to your chart:

```
{
      name: 'Series4',
      type: 'line',
      marker: {
        enabled: false
      },
      index: 1,
      data: [
        [0, 1.5],
        [1, 1.5],
        [2, 1.5]
      ],
    },
```

Here you can see an example how this chart may work: http://jsfiddle.net/ebtygovh/6/

You can also use renderer.path for adding lines to your chart: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.path